# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess with Oracle 8.1.7 DB

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

Is it at all possible to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess with Oracle DB v.8.1.7? I've searched for hours, but failed to find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. ODP.NET Managed Driver only supports databases back to 10.2. As it is a relatively new product, there aren't old versions to fall back on.

The problem is the networking protocol changes over time and Oracle promises backward compatibility for two major versions.

If you must use ODP.NET and Oracle Database 8.1.7, consider using ODP.NET Unmanaged driver version 10.2. It is still available here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html
Of course, using a very old version of ODP.NET introduces it's own limitations, such as lack of Entity Framework support and other things.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any definitive on this, but there is a single line on [this page on Managed ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24odp-2147205.html) that says:

> You will also need access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2) or later, ...

If that is just for the demo, or is a requirement for the driver isn't said.

Also [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/multipledbs-089665.html) says:

> Each ODP.NET client supports connectivity to any currently supported Oracle Database version, such as 10g, 11g, or 9i. That means your ODP.NET 11g (or 10g) client application can access any of these Oracle database versions.

I would suggest to give it a try.

Comment: I've already tested this, and it appears, that it does work with 10.2 or later. Nevertheless, there is not definitive 'NO' for earlier versions. Needless to say, it would be really great to use managed provider in a somewhat outdated environment, so I'm eager for finding an answer.

Comment: If you have that environment, why not simply test it?

Comment: Did so, doesn't work. Yet there is a probability that there is some trick which would allow it to.

Comment: @AlexeyOmelajenko: found another one on 9i. We are getting closer.

Comment: Got it to the point where I can think of no further improvements to app.config, and it started throwing System.IndexOutOfRangeException on opening connection to 8.1.7, while connecting to 10.2 and 11 with same configuration still works like a charm. Trace provides no discernible additions to the cause of such behaviour.

Comment: Can you give the exact error, maybe I can pinpoint it in the source. It looks though that it isn't supported, and if it isn't, you shouldn't use it (IMHO).

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR(Int32 reqCount, Boolean bForPoolPopulation, ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, String instanceName)

Comment: Ah, well, it would appear that it just doesn't work, as plain as that. Perhaps issuing a ticket to developer is in order — final exception message is unclear as hell.