# Legacy SSMigrationAssistant for Oracle 7.3?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, legacy-database

Im unable to get any connectivity to Oracle 7.3 using the current SSMA from Microsoft.  There is no legacy download anymore and i think i need an older version, 6.0. I keep getting two-task connection potocol errors when I use the tnsnames method to define a service. This works with the schema manager in the legacy oracle tools but no matter what i try Im unable to get a connection in the new SSMA without seeing that error.  I should say im on a windows 7 vm for legacy reasons.

I have tried using a linked server in sql 2008 and 2012 which would allow me to make views.  I could then bring it into Entity Framework, which is the ultimate goal, but same result as above.

Anyone had a similar issue and happen to have an older SSMA?

Comment: Why are you still using oracle 7. I know it was a good version of the database but it's been out of support for what? 20 years? Can't you migrate the data to a more modern version instead of trying to rebuild an obsolete operating environment?

Comment: We're migrating to SQL, which is why i need connectivity using migration assisstant. The legacy VM was built to support a migration to SQL server before we run a custom import into our product.  We have no control over the clients setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Client/Server Interoperability Support [ID 207303.1]](https://82star.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/clientserver-interoperability-support-id-207303-1/)
For Oracle Server 7.3 you need oracle client 7.3 or 8.0.5-8.1.7 or 9.0

[Oracle8 i 8.1.7 Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/oracle8i-085806.html)

To configure oracle client `SQL*Net V1, V2 ,tnsnames.ora` read [SQL*Net FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Net_FAQ)

I installed Oracle 7.3 very long ago in 1996 :).

**Update**

You can migrate to the free version of the Oracle 11 XE version or use an RDS instance of Oracle in the Amazon cloud with free 1-year service .
Use the utility `exp` and `imp`. These utilities are no longer being developed and are not supported, but are necessary for migration from very old versions.

- Migration plan:
- Define the necessary schemes and users for migration in the source
  database, table spaces.
- Install the free version of Oracle 11 or create an RDS instance of Oracle in the Amazon cloud with free 1-year service.
- Create the required tablespaces.
- Create profiles, users and roles.
- Import the dump file.
- Make the migration in mssql.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using SQL*Net and TNSNAMES.ORA and can successfully connect with Oracle ODBC 32bit Test app by selecting the Machine DSN.  It then pops up with the service name from the TNSNAMES.ORA, the username and sits waiting for a password.  

This gives me hope I actually can connect, but not through the latest Migration assistant or SQL Server.

Comment: I'm trying my best not to start this process with a migration to another Oracle version, otherwise my 'go-live' process will be:
1. Migrate to later Oracle
2. Use SSMA to migrate that to SQL Server
3. Use EntityFramework on the SQL data
4. Run Custom Import into new system.

The reason I need a custom migration is because this is a legacy version of our current product which needs processing and cleaning before it hits our system.  The migration itself was built for another clients data, so getting it into SQL and re-using as much of that work as possible was the plan.

Comment: I've also noticed a problem with failing to register the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from ODP.NET. I'm currently getting a fresh VM up to re-install ODP.NET

Comment: @ChristopherGibson ODP.NET Managed Driver only supports databases back to 10.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546383/oracle-manageddataaccess-with-oracle-8-1-7-db